# Python equivalent syntax for verbatim string literal in C#

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to write to file a multi-line text in a way that the text is written as is, for example:

```
file.write("Hello {0} Hello1 {0}".format("world"))
```

So the result file will be:

```
Hello world  
Hello1 world
```

And not look like :

```
Hello world  
[many spaces] Hello1 world
```

I also want to try not using `\r\n`
I know in C# we can write `@` before string and all is done like I want

Comment: Not that I do much care about it , but I wonder why people decremented to -2 in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
file_handle.write("""Hello {0}
Hello1 {0}""".format("world"))
```

You can use the [`textwrap.dedent()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) function to strip common leading whitespace:

```
from textwrap import dedent

s = dedent("""\
           Hello {0}
           Hello1 {0}""")
file_handle.write(s.format("world"))
```

I'd recommend against doing either of those though. I'd either split it into two calls (that would each still have a `'\n'` in them), or just use `'\n'` in the one string.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it so unrecommended to use the `dedent` solution?

Comment: @JavaSa, IMO, it makes for ugly code, versus just including a newline in the string. This is especially true for short strings; I would feel differently about a large, multi-line string.

Comment: Great my example is short, but my real usage will be multi line ;)

Comment: @JavaSa, there's no "wrong" way to do it; it's a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

Multiline strings (triple quotes) should work here.

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""Hello {0}
Hello1 {0}""".format("world"))
```

I also agree with @Cyphase, if there is no important reason for you to avoid `\n`, I'd rather use:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Hello {0}\nHello1 {0}".format("world"))
```